# MySQL Error 1064 when using SELECT ... WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue when trying to query data from my MySQL database. Here is the PHP that generates the query: `$q = "SELECT * FROM tclog" . (isset($id) ? " WHERE tcuid='$id';" : ";");`

Here is the query that it generates: `SELECT * FROM tclog WHERE tcuid='55609bb380d9a3.92986475';`

The peculiar part of this issue is that, from one page, the query runs just fine, yet from another page, the query fails. The only difference between the pages is that one page gets the entire SQL script from a form on itself (with `action=""` and don't worry, it's password-protected and forces SSL), while another page (the one shown above which doesn't work) generates the script using just the id variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are missing a closing `)` in your `$q = "SELECT * FROM tclog" . (isset($id) ? " WHERE tcuid='$id';" : ";";`. Is that just a copy/paste error here? Your generated query looks okay. Is there a full error message you could share? `MySQL Error 1064` could mean different issues, and we can't tell without the rest of the message.

Comment: "one page gets the entire SQL script from a form on itself (with action="" and don't worry, it's password-protected and forces SSL)" - Don't worry? That is the biggest mistake there is! WHY put SQL query in a form?

Comment: @RonDadon it's temporary for development, and checks to ensure that the user is logged in (using session cookies) and that SSL is being used (using `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`). If either of these checks fails, it does not execute the query, and redirects the user to either the login page or the current page using HTTPS. Don't worry, I thought this through.

Comment: @Sean yes that is a copy and paste error. Thanks. There are no syntax errors.

Comment: What is the error message in full?

Comment: Notice that SSL and a password does not protect you from a logged in user who manipulates the code. If you use this in your final production version, you will get SQL injections.

Comment: @AbcAeffchen I don't think it counts as *injection* if the entire query comes from user-land :)

Comment: @Phil This is so right. I'm still laughing ^^

Comment: NOTE: a terminating semicolon is not usually sent as part of the SQL text through a database interface such as mysqli or PDO. My suspicion is that the `$id` variable doesn't have a value in the context where the variable is being evaluated into the SQL string. Code is **vulnerable** to **SQL Injection**. (We don't *worry* about it when we use patterns that aren't vulnerable,) Potentially unsafe values incorporated into the text of a SQL statement *must* be properly escaped. A better pattern is to use **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**.

Comment: I suppose @AbcAeffchen @Phil, and this will not be in a final version. We are still in development stages. And only the site administrator's account has access to this page. Ignoring security problems, I have it echo the value of `$q`, which you can see in the question: `SELECT * FROM tclog WHERE tcuid='55609bb380d9a3.92986475';` It is clearly not having trouble generating the query, just executing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the problem. It was actually in the code that calls `mysqli_query`, not in the query itself. Looks like you all enjoyed laughing at my crappy security anyway.

Enjoy,

MagikM18

Comment: Please don't get us wrong: The people who commented came here to see if they can answer your question. From your answer I get, that we could not answer it, with the information you provided, but we saw a security nightmare and told you about it.